# Weird result with MAX and COALESCE in a SQL query when run by different users

Tags: sql-server, max, coalesce, case-when

I have a SQL Server query that tries to choose `NULL` if there is at least one `NULL` in column `PredComplDate` or the latest date stored as `NVARCHAR(30)`

The weird thing is that when I run the query it returns correct results, but when my co-worker runs the query on the same computer it returns different results.

I saved the table created when my co-worker ran the query under a different name and compared it to the one that was created when I run the query. everything is the same, number of records, data type etc, but the below part of the query does not return `NULL` for some reason:

```
SELECT [Reference Number],
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(Predecessors)>0 AND MAX(COALESCE(PredComplDate,'31/12/2099'))='31/12/2099' THEN NULL
        ELSE MAX(PredComplDate)
    END AS LatestPredComplDate
    FROM mytable33
    GROUP BY [Reference Number],Predecessors
```

what is the problem with this query?

`mytable33` has been created by me and `mytable22` has been created by my co-worker. when I query the results are identical:

```
SELECT Predecessors,[Reference Number], PredRefNo,PredComplDate  FROM mytable22

SELECT Predecessors,[Reference Number], PredRefNo,PredComplDate  FROM mytable33
```

[image]

when I run the above-mentioned query on both tables, the result is different:

```
SELECT [Reference Number],
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(Predecessors)>0 AND MAX(COALESCE(PredComplDate,'31/12/2099'))='31/12/2099' THEN NULL
        ELSE MAX(PredComplDate)
    END AS LatestPredComplDate
    FROM mytable22
    GROUP BY [Reference Number],Predecessors

SELECT [Reference Number],
    CASE 
        WHEN LEN(Predecessors)>0 AND MAX(COALESCE(PredComplDate,'31/12/2099'))='31/12/2099' THEN NULL
        ELSE MAX(PredComplDate)
    END AS LatestPredComplDate
    FROM mytable33
    GROUP BY [Reference Number],Predecessors
```

[image]

The expected result is `NULL` for `LastestPredComplDate`

Comment: If LEN(Predecessors) is equal to zero then the first query result can appear.

Comment: What's the value on `Predecessors` for each table?

Comment: As I said all the values are identical

Comment: What is the significance of Predecessors and why can't you post the value of that field?

Comment: I don’t have access to the table right now, will have tmrw morning. I have simplified the query, there is a part that if Predecessors is null it selects a different column, that part works just fine

Comment: I would double check your logic there first to make sure the value returned is what you think it should be. Another way to make sure logic is not broken is to remove the LEN() check from your query entirely. I bet you will find both queries *always* return the results you posted above when you omit that bit.

Comment: The query is invoked from Excel, and uses the same data. Everything that can be visually checked is identical. I cannot find another way of returning Null or Max. In that case I could make sure the logic does not work the same in the background

Comment: @RossBush I added the predecessors to the queries so that you can see they are identical

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can place both clauses in your windowed function like below (if only for clarity sakes):

```
  MAX(CASE WHEN LEN(Predecessors)>0 THEN NULL ELSE PredComplDate END) AS LatestPredComplDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found out the problem. The date (stored as NVARCHAR) format was the culprit. If you have another look at the first image that I posted you can see that the same dates have different formats. One is `04/12/2019` and the other is `4/12/2019`. It turns out the `MAX` function would consider `4/12/2019` larger than `04/12/2019` and that would generate different results.